# C++ - for loop not running

Tags: c++, for-loop

Have a very simple code that I'm building in C++. This is my first C++ code so I'm not entirely sure of syntax in some places. However, for the following code, my for loop isn't running at all! I can't see why not... Can anyone spot the problem?

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std; 


int main () {
/*
 * Use values for wavelength (L) and wave number (k) calculated from linear 
 * dispersion program
 * 
 */


//Values to calculate
  double u;                            //Wave velocity: d*phi/dx
  double du;                  //Acceleration of wave: du/dt

  int t; 
//Temporary values for kn and L (taken from linear dispersion solution)

  float L = 88.7927;
  float kn = 0.0707624;
```

Note: I've left out variable declarations to save on space.

```
/*
 * Velocity potential = phi = ((Area * g)/omega) * ((cosh(kn * (h + z)))/sinh(kn * h))*cos(k*x - omega * t);
 * Velocity of wave, u = d(phi)/dx;
 * Acceleration of wave, du = du/dt;
 */

    for (t = 0; t == 5; t++) {
      cout << "in this loop" << endl;
      u = ((kn * A * g)/omega) * ((cosh(kn * (h + z)))/sinh(kn * h)) *  cos(omega * t);
      du = (A * g * kn) * ((cosh(kn * (h + z)))/sinh(kn * h)) * sin(omega * t); 
      cout << "u = " << u << "\tdu = " << du << endl;
    }

    cout << L << kn << endl;

return 0;

}
```

I've put the "in this loop" as a test and it doens't enter the loop (compiles fine)..

Thanks in advance for taking a look at this!

Comment: I guess that the confusion here is that the loop runs **while** the middle part of the for loop is true, not **until** it is true.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`t` is initialized to `0`, `t == 5` will always be evaluated to be **false**, so your for loop will never run.

update

```
for (t = 0; t == 5; t++) {
```

to

```
for (t = 0; t < 5; t++) {
```

---

*for Statement*

Executes a statement repeatedly until the condition becomes **false**.

> for ( init-expression ; **cond-expression** ; loop-expression )
>
> ```
>       statement;
> ```

Comment: Thanks, I missed that!

Answer (score 1):

Should be:

```
  for (t = 0; t < 5; t++)
```

The syntax of for loop in C++ is:

```
for ( init-expression ; cond-expression ; loop-expression ) 
statement;
```

The statement executes only while cond-expression is true and in your case it is never true.

Answer (score 1):

That's simple: the condition for your `for` loop is `t == 5` - it only loops as long as `t` is five, but since you set `t = 0` at first, it doesn't loop even once. I think `t < 5` is what you want.

Answer (score -1):

Please look at the **condition expression** for **for loop**. **Hint** : You initialized t to 0.